# Wi-Fi connected but no network access

Tags: 14.04, wireless, dual-boot, dell

I have dell inspiron 15r turbo 7520 with windows 8 pre installed. I have dual booted the system with Ubuntu 14.04 and I am new to ubuntu. Wi-Fi is showing to be connected but I am not able to access network. When I enter the command (lspci -nn | grep 0280)on terminal it shows 
Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless -N 2230 [8086:0887] (rev c4)
For iwconfig it shows
eth0 no wireless extensions. 
lo no wireless extensions. 
wlan0 IEEE 802.11bgn ESSID:"UG_4thyr" Mode:Managed Frequency:2.412 GHz 
Access Point: E8:BA:70:61:0A:E7 
Bit Rate=13 Mb/s Tx-Power=16 dBm 
Retry long limit:7 RTS thr:off 
Fragment thr:off Power Management:on 
Link Quality=61/70 Signal level=-49 dBm 
Rx invalid nwid:0 
Rx invalid crypt:0 
Rx invalid frag:0 
Tx excessive retries:0 
Invalid misc:23 
Missed beacon:0

Comment: Can you type `iwconfig` in terminal and paste what it returns here?

Comment: Try the troubleshooting steps listed here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide

Comment: @jessenortoneth0            no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"UG_4thyr"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: E8:BA:70:61:0A:E7   
          Bit Rate=13 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=61/70  Signal level=-49 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:23   Missed beacon:0

Comment: Small suggestion - edit your question to include the output from iwconfig so other users can see.   So wifi is showing to be connected, right? Have you tried going to google.com ? If you can get to google but no other website, your problem may be similar to what i encountered before On my Fedora , i could connect to google but no other website. What i did is go to firefox's about:config page, and search for ipv. Check if network.dns.disableipv6 is set to false

Comment: @Xieerqi I will update the question as per your suggestion and no I am not able to reach for google.com

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that you are using ubuntu 14.04
so do the following steps to correct the problem:

1. Open *Software & Updates* and go to *Additional Divers*
2. Install the fitting driver from there.
3. Restart your system
4. Now your WiFi will definitely work and it will show the WiFi signals (within its range) also.